# How to click Windows key in Java

Tags: java, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I click "Windows" key in Java? I need to emulate pressing Win + ARROW_UP keys. May be this button has Key Unicode and it could be called by `.getKeyFromUnicode()` method? Will be appreciated for any help. Thank you.

Comment: This is for your java program? Not a system wide key press?

Comment: @BevynQ, this is for my java app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **1)** You can simply try this:

```
private void pressKey() {

    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS)
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP); //Windows button is still pressed at this moment
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## **2)** Another variant for solving your task - is sikuli.docs

If you want to simulate pressing and holding one button, while then typing another, use `type(TheKeyDoingTheAction, KeyModifier.TheKeyYoureHoldingDown` It's written like this:

```
 type(Key.UP, KeyModifier.WIN)
```

Please check docs and samples here: http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html

## 3) Finally, you could use the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
```

**Note:** This will work for Win OS only.

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas. This is right what I need. 
Very helpful answer!

Comment: Please, note that this will work for Win OS only.
You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Try out the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)) class to emulate a key press. Use the [Key Event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) class's `VK_WINDOWS` constant to press the windows key (this can be generalized to also press the up key with `VK_UP`):

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
```

Keep in mind the `Robot` class throws an IllegalArgumentException if the key is invalid. I'm not 100% on what happens if you try to press the Windows key on a non-Windows OS.

Comment: Thank you Peter! This is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at KeyEvent from awt:

```
    /**
     * Constant for the Microsoft Windows "Windows" key.
     * It is used for both the left and right version of the key.
     * @see #getKeyLocation()
     * @since 1.5
     */
    public static final int VK_WINDOWS                  = 0x020C;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is for sure an interesting solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void pressKey() {

    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS + KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Loved it.

```
try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS + KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Solved my issue and release is very important.